# How to split a string into multiple arrays in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, csv

I am reading entries from a CSV file and I managed to get every line separated into an array, however, now I need to split those strings into their own separate category arrays. For instance, I have a line that has a building, separated by a comma, a room number separated by a comma, and a device in said room.  Any way I would go about doing this?

Comment: Use an existing CSV library, just search on [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=csv).

Comment: Show some details. Post relevant code and show examples of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the same way you did getting the lines into an array in the first place. Also, are all of the lines formatted the same, or do some have different numbers of items? This sample code assumes that all lines are what you described, "building,room number,device".

```
NSString *CSVString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"csvfile.csv" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *lines = [CSVString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
for (NSString *line in lines) {
    NSArray *components = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    // Do something with the components, like put them into a model object.
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped plenty for getting to what exactly I wanted to do with the values.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

componentsSeparatedByString can help you.

```
 NSString *original = @"building,room_number,device";
 NSArray *fields = [original componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: CSV can be difficult with embedded delimiters.

Comment: It does separate, but all of the components are placed into the same array.  Is there a way I can stop it and switch the array?

Comment: @PrimalDusk maybe you could try Zaph 's solution??
or could you please edit your question to provide some codes? 
like how you read the csv, what object that function return??